# How can an answer without down-votes be voted to be deleted?

Tags: support, answers, vote-to-delete

On *Drupal Answers*, I found a post that got an automatic low-quality flag, and (as consequence of this), two "not an answer" flags. The post has also a vote to delete it, despite its score is not negative.

How is it possible? 20k users can vote to delete, but only when the score of the answer is negative, which is not the case here.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I didn't add the link to the answer because I am going to delete it. `:)`

Comment: It doesn't need to be downvoted if it's from the review queue.

Comment: @John In that case, the vote counter would disappear after the down-vote is removed. I once voted to delete an answer with a score of −1; that answer had then an up-vote, and the vote-to-delete counter vanished.

Comment: @YannisRizos I have tried that on a site where I am a 20K user, and not a moderator. Once the down-vote is removed, the vote-to-delete counter vanishes: [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tdQMy.png), and [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rxqA.png).

Comment: Hm. I guess this is why I shouldn't delete dumb comments.  So @YannisRizos doesn't come along later with the same idea :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the new Low Quality review queue (and *only* from the new LQ review queue), it's possible for members with at least 20K reputation to vote to delete answers with a score equal or less than 0.

The assumption here is that posts in the LQ queue are more likely to be worth deleting out of hand, rather than rated and ranked. The post shown in your screenshot is a *perfect* example of this.

Everywhere else, casting a delete vote requires the post to be scored -1 or less, as before.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that people who "sympathy upvote" bad material interfere with some of the features that allow the community to do its policing work. This is a great example why a community needs it's members on board with downvoting bad content.